# Sending HTTPS Post Request in Android/Java

Tags: java, android

since
sslSocketFactory(javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory)' is deprecated, what should I use instead? Thanks in regards... Deprecated. SSLSocketFactory does not expose its X509TrustManager, which is a field that OkHttp needs to build a clean certificate chain. This method instead must use reflection to extract the trust manager. Applications should prefer to call sslSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory, X509TrustManager), which avoids such reflection.
Sets the socket factory used to secure HTTPS connections. If unset, the system default will be used.

```
try {
                        client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
                                .sslSocketFactory(trustCert().getSocketFactory())
                                .build();
                    } catch (CertificateException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("text/plain");
                    RequestBody body = new FormBody.Builder()
                            .build();
    
                    Request request = new Request.Builder()
                            .url("https://example.com")
                            .method("GET", null)
                            .addHeader("auth-token", token)
                            .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer"+" "+token)
                            .build();
                    Response response = null;
                    try {
                        response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                        odgovor = response.body().string();
                        System.out.println(odgovor);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

      private SSLContext trustCert() throws CertificateException,IOException, KeyStoreException,
                NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {
            AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
            InputStream is = getApplicationContext().getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.gdig2);
            CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
            Certificate ca = cf.generateCertificate(is);
    
            // Create a KeyStore containing our trusted CAs
            String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
            keyStore.load(null, null);
            keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);
    
            // Create a TrustManager that trusts the CAs in our KeyStore
            String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
            TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
            tmf.init(keyStore);
    
            // Create an SSLContext that uses our TrustManager
            SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            context.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
            return context;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use,  #sslSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory, X509TrustManager)

client = new okHttpClient().newBuilder().sslSocketFactory(trustCert().getSocketFactory(), (X509TrustManager) tmf.trustManagers.get(0));